# Passing arguments to OpenCL kernel, before execution finished

Tags: synchronization, opencl, gpgpu

I have the following question about executing OpenCL kernel. Let kernel be some OpenCL kernel. I want to execute it twice with different arguments.

Can I set new arguments to this kernel after calling function "clEnqueueNDRangeKernel" but before this execution is finished? (Will it bring some problems?)

```
kernel = clCreateKernel(...);

clSetKernelArg(kernel, ...);

cl_event event;
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, ..., &event)

clSetKernelArg(kernel, ...);//Can I call this function before "event" is completed?

clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, ...)
```

I saw the documentation on "khronos registry", but I did not found an answer for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I was not too attentive. The answer to my question is "yes". I can set new arguments to a kernel immediately after calling "clEnqueueNDRangeKernel" without waiting for execution result. I found answer here: [khronos forum](https://community.khronos.org/t/calling-the-same-kernel-object-multiple-times/1340/3)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).